# Pluralization Bugs in Rate-Limit Message

Tags: bug, status-completed, rate-limiting, plurals

In the recent (deleted) meta.SO question:

- [Why have I been ban from asking questions from SO? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373735/why-have-i-been-ban-from-asking-questions-from-so)

@Shog9 posted the following screenshot of the rate-limit message that is shown to new users who post sub-par questions.

But there are pretty obvious problems with it:

[image]

> You've asked *1 question**s*** recently, *some of* which *have* not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it's okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your *question**s** have* received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely.
>
> It's been *1 day**s*** since you asked your last question.

Obviously, if we're gonna ask people to use proper grammar, let's start by setting a good example ourselves.

Comment: It takes at least two questions... On every site except Stack Overflow. On SO, having a chance to correct after your first question seemed like a kindness for all involved. Note that it'll usually only kick in if you *try* to ask a second question within a day of your first; after that, you're more likely to just get a warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adam Lear fixed this a few days ago. Thanks for the report!

[image]

Comment: The last line uses the plural "days" too: "_We'll see you in 1 days_"